# Is it possible to get Xcode to build dylibs for a SwiftPM project?

Tags: swift, xcode, dylib, swiftpm

I am building a library using SwiftPM, and it is important for my use case that I link dynamically, so I have a dylib product.

```swift
.library(name: "ExampleLib", type: .dynamic, targets: ["ExampleLib"])
```

When I build the library with `swift build`, there is a `libExampleLib.dylib` produced in the `.build` folder.
However, if I open the `Package.swift` file with Xcode and build like usual, there are no `.dylib` files produced in the `DerivedData` folder. This causes all my tests which rely on dynamic linking to fail because the dylib is not in the products directory.

Is there something I can do to convince Xcode to build the dylibs, or is it necessary to build from the command line?